# Running Python script on opening QGIS project?

Tags: pyqgis

I have a .csv file containing financial data which is generated on a regular basis outside QGIS. Then I want to create a PyQGIS script that will add the .csv file as a layer in my project. (The idea here is I want to have the up-to-date financial data as attributes data for one of the shapefiles in the project).

Is there a way to run the script automatically as soon as I open the QGIS project?

Comment: Why not store the layer as a view in a database, and use your csv creation script to instead import the data to table as part of the view, the other part being the spatial component?

Answer (score 13):

Put your script in .qgis/python/startup.py and it should run when QGIS is opened. However, this will run with any project you open, which you may not want.

So you might be better off setting up a python macro in the specific project. File > Project properties > Macros. Enable macrcos by checking the box.

```
def openProject():
    wack your code here!

def saveProject():
    pass

def closeProject():
    pass
```

Comment: +1 Marcos are the way to go. If you have a lot of code I would suggest putting it in it's own `.py` file next to the project and importing it from `openProject` rather then putting lots of logic in the blocks.  Makes it easier to test and debug.