# How does one create an "Embedded Widget" in the Legend section of a Vector Layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

> By default, QGIS provides transparency widget but this can be extended
>   by plugins registering their own widgets and assign custom actions to
>   layers they manage.
>   [from QGIS 2.18 Manual](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#legend-properties)

How can I create such a widget?

Comment: I am not completely sure, but does this post answer your question? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232367/showing-transparency-slider-by-default-in-layers-panel-of-qgis