# Launch a QGIS plugin from a batchfile

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, pyqgis-3, python-3

After having built a QGIS 3 plugin, I'd like to know how could I call my plugin without clicking on the plugin bar of QGIS to launch it.

I've tried implement a first batch file for it :

```
REM changer OSGEO4W_ROOT pour aller sur le dossier du shell
SET OSGEO4W_ROOT=C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.4
SET QGISNAME=qgis
SET QGIS=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\%QGISNAME%
SET QGIS_PREFIX_PATH=%QGIS%
REM Gdal setup
SET PATH=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin;%QGIS%\bin;%PATH%
SET PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python37
SET PYTHONPATH=%QGIS%\python;%PYTHONPATH%

REM Launch python
REM python "C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Roaming\QGIS\QGIS3\profiles\default\python\plugins\tombarel\zoom_snap_dialog.py"
pause
```

The problem is I don't know how to launch the plugin from my batchfile once I've opened QGIS (version 3.4.4)

I've seen previous answers where `fTools`module was still available for QGIS 2.X. but about the version 3 of QGIS I can't figure out how to do a standalone program which actions the plugin

I've tried to look at the `run()`method in the plugin main python file but I couldn't find a way either to call it from another python file

Comment: So, you want your plugin to automatically start once you open a QGIS-project?

Comment: Yes, once QGIS opened and the project loaded, I'd like a program (out of QGIS) to send a signal to QGIS to start and open the plugin

Comment: search for **startup.py** which is automatically run by qgis at startup and call your plugin in this script.

Comment: If you want to autostart your plugin once QGIS is started `startup.py` is the best way to go. Otherwise if you want to start it while QGIS is running from another application you need a mechanism to send and receive data between different processes. I would use startup.py to start a TCP socket server in a separate thread listening for incoming connections. From anywhere else a client may connect and send some data. If the server recognizes this data, it gets reference to QGIS instance and triggers some action associated with this kind of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for you answers, I've looked at the `startup.py` file of QGIS 3 but it really does sound challenging at my level, If for example I wanted to launch the plugin once QGIS started, should I just call for the `plugin.py`and `plugin_dialog.py`files in `startup.py` ? Or am I missing a step ?
I understand the process you've offered with the TCP server but isn't there a way to receive a signal from a PyQt5 GUI for instance ?

Comment: This question is about a similar problem. https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/287057/46073

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've see this post but I'm getting the same error at the call of `plugin=[plugin_name].classFactory(iface)` :
It's doing the error : `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` at the line of my plugin's script : 
`locale = QSettings().value('locale/userLocale')[0:2]`
did you have this mistake too ?