# Executing script in QGIS after complete load?

Tags: pyqgis

I'm looking for a solution to run a Python script after the complete load of QGIS.
The startup.py is executed during (or before) complete load, so it doesn't work well. I would like to trigger the event "complete load", but I don't know where to look. Where should I look?

Comment: Have you tried to launch QGIS in a terminal with the `--code "path_to\my_startup_script.py"` argument ? [source](https://madmanwoo.gitlab.io/foss4g-python-workshop/startup/)

Comment: look at this https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/89907/49538